MS Access - Data difference calculation in Calculated field
In MS Access, I want to calculate "Aging" by using the today's date and Closed Date. Datediff is not heling, any pointers
I tried Datediff (Not allowed). Also could not get Today dates, if i need to do simple Date1-Date2 approach.

Are you asking about a calculated field in table design?

First, [Closed Date] should be of data type Date.
Next, use DateDiff in an expression for the calculated field.
In a query:
Aged Days: DateDiff("d",[Closed Date],Date())

As ControlSource for a textbox on a form or report:
=DateDiff("d",[Closed Date],Date())

If [Closed Date] is text, convert with DateValue:
Aged Days: DateDiff("d",DateValue([Closed Date]),Date())


I used the approach suggested by you, its not working. When I try to save it throws an error "The expression Datediff can't be used in the calculated column".

That is true - see the comment from @HansUp - that option is limited to simple expressions. Do use a query or a form/report as shown.

Sorry I could not find Gustav's response
